# Difference between Comparable and Object type

Tags: java, comparable

Currently am working on an assignment that puts the concepts of `Comparable` to application.

I wrote this simple method that allows the input of a `Comparable[]` array. This method returns the minimum value of any given array input. Using the `.compareTo()` method, I am able to really extend this method to allow object types of really, anything, whether it's custom implementation like a `Point` class (which we did for the assignment, but not shown here).

```
public static Comparable getMinimum(Comparable[] inputArray)
{
    Comparable newObj = inputArray[0];
    for(int i = 0; i < inputArray.length; i++)
    {
        Integer retValue = (inputArray[i]).compareTo(newObj);
        if(retValue < 0)
        {
            newObj = inputArray[i];
        }
    }
    return newObj;
}
```

My question is - what is this `Comparable` type? Looking at the Java API, it didn't really reveal much. Why are we using the `Comparable` type as opposed to the `Object` type, which also includes types like `int`, `double`, `String`, etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use `Comparable` because the type `Comparable` is generic, allowing you to specify exactly what type your are "comparable" to, while also keeping things type-safe. The `Object` base class does not contain such a thing.


Also, you're not using the generic version of `Comparable`. That's a problem, you're using the old type of Comparable.

Comment: Ah I see! So the difference between `Comparable` and `Object` is that it's type-safe? Also, where do you specify exactly what type you are comparable to?

Comment: @theGreenCabbage That's the main reason. Also I noticed something in your code that I pointed out in my question edit.

Comment: It appears the professor's answer keys are also deprecated as well, since mine bares resemblance to his. What is the non-deprecated way to do this?

Comment: @theGreenCabbage You use the generic version of `Comparable` instead: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html

Comment: What is the difference between the generic version and the one you linked to, @YasmaniLlanes?

Comment: @Mo2 The one I linked to is the generic version.

Comment: I meant what is the difference between the one you linked to and the one OP is using, other than the diamond parameter? @YasmaniLlanes

Comment: @Mo2 That the generic one provides type safety. The class implementing `Comparable` won't have to cast the object passed onto `compareTo`.

Answer (score 5):

A comparable type is a reference type whose class `C` implements the `Comparable<C>` interface.  The interface defines one method:  `int compareTo(<T> other)`.  Read the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) for details.

- Primitive types (e.g. `int` and `double`) are not `Comparable` in that sense because primitive types are not reference types.
- The type `Object` is a reference type, BUT it is not a comparable because it does not implement `Comparable<Object>`.
- The type `String` is a reference type, AND it implements `Comparable<String>`.  Therefore it is a comparable type.  And this is clear from the javadoc for String which says:

  ```
  public final class String extends Object
      implements Serializable, Comparable<String>, CharSequence
  ```

---

The difference between [primitive types](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html) and reference types is fundamental in Java.  Primitive types are `boolean`, `byte`, `char`, `short`, `int`, `long`, `float` and `double`.  Reference types are Java classes and Java array types.

---

Now in your example, you are actually using the `Comparable` interface as a raw type.  If you compile this code with a Java 5 or later compiler, it will give you compiler warnings about using raw types.  This doesn't substantially change the answer, but in effect you are now effectively talking about implementing `Comparable<?>` rather `Comparable<T>` and the method is effectively `compareTo(Object)`.

Comment: By primitive types do you mean the `Object` type?

Comment: @theGreenCabbage - No.  `Object` is not a primitive type.

Comment: I still don't fully understand the difference between Comparable or Object from your answer :/

Comment: This is a better answer than the accepted one, IMO.

Answer (score 0):

Comparable is an Interface, not a class. Interface enforce any class which implements it to have the method implementations of the methods declared in the interface. Comparable interface declares a method called compareTo for comparing two objects (useful for sorting a set of objects). So if a class implements Comparable interface, we know for sure that we can compare the instances of that class.
Object, doesn't declare any method for object comparison. So you cannot compare two objects directly.